# WPF Datagrid ComboboxColumn Databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have a very simple database containing two tables, one represents Books and the other Genres. I've used Entity Framework model-first generation to create it, now I want to represent it in a WPF Datagrid.
The Datagrid is supposed to display the Genre of a Book as a Combobox column, but I'm having trouble binding it correctly.

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider IsAsynchronous="True" x:Key="BookDataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:BookDataProvider}">
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Books" ObjectInstance="{StaticResource BookDataProvider}" MethodName="GetAllBooks"></ObjectDataProvider>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="GenreDataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:GenreDataProvider}" IsAsynchronous="True">
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Genres" ObjectInstance="{StaticResource GenreDataProvider}" MethodName="GetAllGenres"></ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Books}}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="179*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="32*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="292*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="311" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="503" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ISBN" Binding="{Binding ISBN}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Author" Binding="{Binding Author_AuthorName}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Visibility="Visible" IsReadOnly="False"  Header="Genre" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Genre}" SelectedValuePath="Genre" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Genres}}"/>                
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

This shows the list of genres in the combox, but I can't get it to show the correct genre for each book when I run the application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use both the selected item binding and the selected value path. I'd go with the first. Also you shouldn't handle the selected item changed event, that's not very mvvm-ish, but instead handle INotifyPropertyChanged of your entity.

If that doesn't fix the problem, then I think the problem must be in your model class. For this binding to work, the genre property of your entity object has to be set to the exact same instance of a genre from the available genres list, ie. the two have to be the exact same object.